# Screen options on a different computer

Tags: screen-options

Is it possible to keep dashboard screen options (for instance, not showing custom fields) across computers?

Comment: the reason you asked this question is it doesn't work across computers? that's weird, the preference is stored in database actually so it shouldn't have this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do work across many computers, as long as you're logged in with the same username. If they don't, try clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

Screen options are server side admin options, not client side. Use different WP accounts to vary the screen options displayed.